# How to quote content from a paper?

Tags: quoting

In markdown, we use `>` to quote content. In LaTeX, how can I quote the content of a specific paper?

Comment: It is known as "blockquote". Search, and you will find several ways to do it, using LaTeX.

Comment: `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}`

Comment: Package `csquotes` provides a more powerful interface to block quotes and inline quotes.

Comment: For longer block quotes, i.e., quotes that are longer than a single paragraph, LaTeX provides the `quotation` environment.